# How do you achieve volumetric fall-off, inside a cylinder?

Tags: volumetrics

[image: node setup]

It is a cyl with volume inside it.
I want to have this fog fade away from bottom to top.

I have tried using separate XYZ as previously suggested - this is what happened and it is not what im wanting:

[image: node setup with separate XYZ]

To be even clearer - i wish to have this noise pattern gradually fade
[image: gradient]

Like a gradient, white being visible, black being invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix your nodes with a *MixRGB* (*Multiply* mode) like in this setup:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly!

No idea how people just seem to know these things - one day i'll be the same